# Spring boot hikaricp connection-timeout vs connectionTimeout

Tags: spring-boot, hikaricp

when I google the Hikaricp connection properties, I found two major difference, for example:

https://www.javadevjournal.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-hikari/

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-hikari

```
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout = 20000
spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=30000
```

when I look into https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#configuration-knobs-baby

I cannot find '''.connection-timeout'''

what is the difference between connection-timeout vs connectionTimeout?

this is one of the difference I found on net.

Comment: connection-timeout is probably either e deprecation or a misspelling, i wouldn't worry about it and use the one which is stated in the hikari wiki (connectionTimeout)

Comment: There is no difference, they bind to the same property. You can user either camel-case or kebab-case, which Spring Boot likes to call relaxed binding. Which is also explained in [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-relaxed-binding).

Answer (score 9):

Spring Boot utilized something they call [relaxed binding](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-relaxed-binding) and each of those properties would endup in the same place. The `connectionTimeout` property of the `HikariDataSource`.

In fact you could also use `_` or when providing a environment variable use uppercase names.

```
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=20000
spring.datasource.hikari.connection_timeout=20000
spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=30000
SPRING_DATASOURCE_HIKARI_CONNECTIONTIMEOUT=30000
```

All of the aforementioned properties would eventually be bound to the `HikariDataSource.connectionTimeout` property. They are all different representations of the same. The latter is mainly to overcome the limitation of not being able to use `-` in environment variables in Linux/Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the actual code in Hikari -  setting up the configuration and the actual property is `connectionTimeout`. Spring would most likely invoke it via setter when provided this setting in Spring configuration

```
public class HikariConfig implements HikariConfigMXBean
{
.....................
.....................

private volatile long connectionTimeout;

/** {@inheritDoc} */
   @Override
   public long getConnectionTimeout()
   {
      return connectionTimeout;
   }

   /** {@inheritDoc} */
   @Override
   public void setConnectionTimeout(long connectionTimeoutMs)
   {
      if (connectionTimeoutMs == 0) {
         this.connectionTimeout = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
      }
      else if (connectionTimeoutMs < 250) {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("connectionTimeout cannot be less than 250ms");
      }
      else {
         this.connectionTimeout = connectionTimeoutMs;
      }
   }
```